# Threads Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The question is as follows:

Three threads are started simultaneously as follows:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
```

The output of the first thread(t1) should be the input to the second thread(t2) and the output of 2nd thread (t2) should be the input of the third thread(t3).

Can you please tell me me the logic?

I know we can use wait and notify methods of objects. But can I get the algorithm or logic for achieving this output?

Comment: Is there a single output from each thread? If so, you shouldn't be using separate threads at all... the second thread won't be able to do anything useful until the first thread has finished, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by o/p and i/p? Output/input?

Comment: if they depend on each other like this, why are you using threads?

Comment: o/p refers to output and i/p refers to input

Comment: @Nicholas: I believe so - I've edited the question to make it simpler to read.

Comment: @user2392544: Please just use the full words instead in future. It's much clearer to read, especially for non-native English speakers.

Comment: **Why** are the threads started simultaneously, given the dependencies? It might make sense to use a thread, for example to get long operations out of the event dispatch thread, but not three in parallel.

Comment: You can use observer pattern to communicate between threads. Java has its implementation in `Observable` and `Observer` classes.

Comment: It is an interview question asked in a company? He asked how will you achieve the same?

Comment: @ Mach: U mean setObject1 as setResource1, where are we notifying the thread that was started?

Comment: Can we use wait and notify to achieve the same?

Comment: @user2392544: That'd generally require modifying the thread's runnable.  If you haven't been given any details to that end, i'd assume them off limits.

Comment: @cHao Can you tell me the logic by modifying the thread's runnable?

Comment: If i'm misreading the question, and there will be a constant stream of stuff rather than a return value or a single output, then i'd much rather give each thread an output queue and let them post stuff to it.  Interested parties can wait for a message from the appropriate thread's queue.

Comment: @cHao your previous comment is hate speech , please comply with terms here , thank you

Comment: @anshulkatta: You really need to look up the definition of "hate speech".  I'm not denigrating a person or ethnic group here, and architectures don't have feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper class for you. It implements two resource locks in a singleton helper class.

Let each thread get the instance by using `ResourceLock.getInstance()`. Let thread 2 call `getResource1()` and wait until thread 1 is done and puts its output in `setResource1()`. This releases the lock and thread two's call to `getResource1()` returns.

Repeat for thread 2 & 3

It's not a really good idea to call hanging functions without a timeout. There is therefore a timeout of 10 seconds, edit for your needs.

```
package com.madinsweden.test;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class ResourceLock {

    protected static final int TIMEOUT = 10000; //ms

    private CountDownLatch mLock1;
    private CountDownLatch mLock2;

    private Object mObject1;
    private Object mObject2;

    private static ResourceLock mInstance;

    private ResourceLock() {
        mLock1 =  new CountDownLatch(1);
        mLock2 =  new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public static ResourceLock getInstance() {
        if (null == mInstance) {
            mInstance = new ResourceLock();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }


    public void setObject1(Object o) {
        mObject1 = o;
        mLock1.countDown();
    }

    public Object getResource1() {
        try {
            mLock1.await(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Timeout of resource lock 1");
        }
        return mObject1;
    }


    public void setObject2(Object o) {
        mObject2 = o;
        mLock2.countDown();
    }

    public Object getResource2() {
        try {
            mLock2.await(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Timeout of resource lock 2");
        }
        return mObject2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Race conditions, type unsafety, *and* a singleton?  And not even a mention that this situation probably shouldn't exist in the first place...?  No hire.

Comment: cHao Please elaborate on the race condition.

Comment: For one, `getInstance()`.  (Two threads calling it at the same time could end up creating two `ResourceLock`s, and anything posted to one wouldn't be visible at the other.)  That should be synchronized.

Comment: Secondly, you're unnecessarily conflating CPU time to wall-clock time by using a timeout.  If a task legitimately takes over 10 seconds, you still assume it failed.  Yeah, you can increase the timeout, but then you still can run into issues on slower machines.  There's no compelling reason not to let thread2 wait as long as it takes for thread1 to output something.

Comment: Thirdly, in the event multiple items are posted (which is the only case where a setup like this makes sense), if thread1 posts a second item before thread2 has retrieved the first one, the first one just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use ExecutorServices.  This means passing work between threads easier.

```
// fields
ExecutorServices service1 = ...
ExecutorServices service2 = ...
ExecutorServices service3 = ...


// Task1 submits to service2
service1.submit(new Task1());

// service2 submits to service3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to doing this. As point out by Jon, there's not point in running threads this way as you are causing them to me blocked on the output of other threads, effectively not achieving parallelization.

My "preferred" solution would be use `ExecutorService`, as mentioned by Peter, albeit a bit differently. Here's one naive approach.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    final Future<String> output1 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
       @Override public String call() {
           // do Something
           return "a String from Task #1";

       } 
    });



    final Future<String> output2 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override public String call() throws Exception{
           // do Something
           // Wait for the output of the above task using `Future.get()`.
           return output1.get() + ", a String from Task #2";

       }

    });

    Future<String> output3 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override public String call() throws Exception{
           // do Something
           return output2.get() + ", a String from Task #3";

       }

    });

    System.err.print("Output from 3rd task: " + output3.get());
```

---

Other ways to do this using threads: Shared Blocking Data Structure (e.g. `BlockingQueue` between Threads to safely publish results. If no results are passed and just require a signal of termination to the other threads, you case use `CountDownLatch`es.